# converting a timestamp into multiple timezones

Tags: php, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Timezone conversion in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505681/timezone-conversion-in-php)

Here is a simple example of what i want to do.

I have a variable `$time` containing a timestamp.

Now, I want to convert it into timestamp of different timezones

Is there a way to do this without using the function `date_default_timezone_set()` multiple times ?

I know my point might seem confusing and point less so please clarify any doubt in comments.

If I have, for example, 100 calls to change it:-

1. It affects my other functions
2. The functions name suggests its default
3. It slows down the script.

Comment: What exact problem do you with calling that function? :)

Comment: Exactly my point. Instead of writing it here, you should have considered including this information in the question itself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/datetime) object and set the time zone as required using the [SetTimezone()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) method.

For example, the following code:-

```
$datetime = new DateTime();
var_dump($datetime->getTimezone()->getName());
var_dump($datetime->format(DateTime::ISO8601));
$datetime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
var_dump($datetime->format(DateTime::ISO8601));
$datetime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
var_dump($datetime->format(DateTime::ISO8601));
```

Gave me the following output:-

```
string 'Europe/London' (length=13)
string '2012-06-20T20:33:29+0100' (length=24)
string '2012-06-20T19:33:29+0000' (length=24)
string '2012-06-20T15:33:29-0400' (length=24)
```

My dev server default TZ is Europe/London, so you may get slightly different results.

There is a list of [supported timezones here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

Comment: Haha. I understand :P i also posted that from my android :P

Comment: Here are some DateTime-based timezone conversion examples - http://blog.serverdensity.com/2009/03/21/handling-timezone-conversion-with-php-datetime/

Answer (score 0):

To give you a sample of something ive done for creating a date in different time zones.. Here is what i have done

```
function create_date($format, $time, $offset = -6)
{   
    return gmdate($format, $time + (3600 * $offset));
}
```

If you want to keep this in timestamp format just modify it to look like this.

```
function create_date($time, $offset = -6)
{   
    return $time + (3600 * $offset);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If you need to enter in timezone in text form I would use the list from [PHP Timezone List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755704/php-timezone-list) question and then in the function do a simple lookup on that array to get the offset to make this work.

**NOTICE:**

for this to work correctly, the original time must be GMT time

Comment: This needs to enter the offset like the old method. Which means i must have offset for each timezone. When php has the data for us i would like to use it in some way :)

Comment: @kritya see update.  I assume you mean you would want to do something like create_date(123456789,'US/Eastern');

Comment: What data do you have? Only one timestamp and you want to get that same timestamp 23 other times for all the other time zones?

Comment: Hmm. I have a single timestamp. And my script is in an infinite loop which monitors changes in a log file. Different users have different timezones and i would to convert it into that in which the user wants. A bit clear now ?