# date_default_timezone_set() seems to have no effect

Tags: php, time

I was trying to get the `time()` on a PHP page (localhost), but it seemed it was returning wrong dates. So I tried:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");
echo "America/Chicago:".time();
echo "<br>";

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Helsinki");
echo "Europe/Helsinki:".time();
```

Which outputs:

```
America/Chicago:1439981623
Europe/Helsinki:1439981623
```

How is it that these two values are the same? How can I make sure this particular php-page returns times in my timezone, without changing the php.ini file?

Comment: I think you can't set default timezone multiple times.

Comment: See the answer to [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125568/converting-a-timestamp-into-multiple-timezones) questions, it may help you.

Comment: Thanks for that. I still wonder why it doesn't work though. It seems like `date_default_timezone_set` has no influence at all, even if I only use it once.

Comment: I've answered that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated at php.net documentation's first [highly voted contribution note](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) by "Timo K":

> The function time() returns always timestamp that is timezone
>   independent (=UTC).

That said, you must use `DateTime` objects and it's methods to deal with multiple timezones.