# How to show GMT Time based upon country in php

Tags: php, datetime, gmt

I want to show GMT Timebased upon country. If suppose, some  user from india, register into my application i should append GMT time as GMT +5 into my database. If suppose, some other user from france, register into my application i should append GMT time as GMT +1 into my database.

Comment: Why do you need GMT? PHP offers [Named Timezones](http://il1.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it in PHP, you'll need geolocation for this. There are two ways: the homebrew way, or the API way. Depending on the resolution you would like, things might differ. Bear in mind that this **will not** magically detect proxies. The trade-offs are between efficiency and housekeeping.

## Homebrew

Pick up a geolocation DB and query it for the IP subset, which will give you the country. Keep a list of timezones for countries. It's a pain, which is why I'm not going to give code for it.

## API

This one is trivial:

```
<?php 
  $geoloc = file_get_contents("http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?format=json&key=<API KEY>&ip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
  if ($geoloc && ($r = json_decode($geoloc)) !== false) {
    // Your timezone is in $r->timeZone in the format "+/-i:ii"
  }
?>
```

You'll need an API key for ipinfodb, which you can get at this address: http://ipinfodb.com/register.php

Comment: P.S: not affiliated with ipinfodb, just so you know.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, there's not a `server-based/PHP` method for getting local time.

You have to get it from the client via `Javascript`.  Google `bitbucket timezone detect` and use it to set a `local_timezone` cookie that you can read from PHP and set via `date_default_timezone_set()`

```
//get the client ip and assign it to variable
$IP=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
//if you using localhost you can check using follow variable
//$IP = '202.71.158.30';
//pass the ip as a parameter for follow URL it will return the country
$country = file_get_contents('http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip='.$IP);
//show the country
echo $country
```

Further more, here is the link which will help you to get the GTM timezone...

[How do I get Greenwich Mean Time in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851574/how-do-i-get-the-gmt-time-in-php)

You need to implement your own logic, for example, get the client's time and deduct it from GTM-0, what you will get will be the GTM (hours).. Hope you get what I want to say..

Hope it helps.

Comment: thnks...Mostly the example will be like this <?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");
echo date_default_timezone_get();
?> but i want to display GMT 5+ for india..I should not hardcode any value

Comment: Plz tell me if country is india..how to print GMT +5