# is time() returning same value for all locations (time zones)?

Tags: php

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851744/1081753) it's said:

> A timestamp is the number of seconds since Midnight 1 January 1970, GMT. It doesn't matter where you are in the world, a given timestamp represents the exact same moment in time, regardless of time zones.

So I tried that:

```
$date_str="2010-01-10 12:00";

$TimeZone_toronto=new DateTimeZone('America/Toronto');
$date_obj_toronto=new DateTime($date_str, $TimeZone_toronto);
$date_time_stamp_toronto=$date_obj_toronto->format('U'); 

$TimeZone_GMT=new DateTimeZone('GMT');
$date_obj_GMT=new DateTime($date_str, $TimeZone_GMT);
$date_time_stamp_GMT=$date_obj_GMT->format('U');
```

Based on the quote above: should be $date_time_stamp_toronto==$date_time_stamp_GMT

But here are the values:

```
$date_time_stamp_toronto = 1263142800
$date_time_stamp_GMT     = 1263124800
```

So => $date_time_stamp_toronto!=$date_time_stamp_GMT because:

```
1263142800!=1263124800
```

Where is the truth?

Comment: The truth is it works fine http://3v4l.org/Ms108 . Also, don't use GMT, use UTC instead http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php See the red box halfway down he page.

Comment: You're missing that `2010-01-10 12:00` in Toronto and `2010-01-10 12:00 GMT` do **not** refer to the same moment in time.

Comment: vascowhite: I will get same timestamps as you showed in demi if $date_str="now";.. but what about $date_str="2010-01-10 12:00";

Comment: Why would you think that 12:00 in Toronto = 12:00 GMT? It obviously doesn't. http://3v4l.org/9T7sJ Does that help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***"2010-01-10 12:00"*** in Toronto and Greenwich ***local time*** respectively are obviously two very different times with a different timestamp.

Comment: If `2010-01-10 12:00` ***local time*** is different based on the timezone, why isn't `now` (assumingly also local time)? [**DEMO**](http://3v4l.org/fCUv0).

Comment: Because ***now*** is whatever time it is ***now*** at that location. 12 o'clock at that location is not *now* and it's 12 o'clock at different times in different parts of the world. Are you expecting "now" to mean "take whatever wall clock time it is now *in my timezone* and use that same number as the wall clock time in a different timezone"? That makes no sense. :)

Comment: But surely `now` when specifying a timezone ***should*** refer to `now` in **that** timezone, right?

Comment: 2010-01-19 12:00 in Toronto is 2010-01-19 16:00 GMT

Comment: @h2o ...yes...?! And "now" in Berlin is a different wall clock time than "now" in Tokyo, yet both have the same UNIX timestamp, because it's *now*.

Comment: @deceze Oh wow - I must be half asleep - time to go home because my brain is obviously done for today. Thanks for the ELI5 explanation.