# How to get GMT date in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss in PHP

Tags: php, date, gmt

I want to get the current date in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format.

I have tried:

`gmdate('yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss \G\M\T', time());`

Its returning a wierd date:

`13131313-1111-2323 0707:1111:3131`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You don't have to repeat those format identifiers . For `yyyy` you just need to have `Y`, etc.

```
gmdate('Y-m-d h:i:s \G\M\T', time());
```

In fact you don't even need to give it a default time if you want current time

```
gmdate('Y-m-d h:i:s \G\M\T');  // This is fine for your purpose
```

**[Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php)**

You can get that list of identifiers **[Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)**

Answer (score 14):

Try this

Check this [How do i get the gmt time in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851574/how-do-i-get-the-gmt-time-in-php)

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
```

Answer (score 3):

You had selected the time format wrong

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');

echo date("Y-m-d,h:m:s");
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below date function to get current time in MySQL format/(As requested on question also)

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are repeating the `y,m,d`.

Instead of

```
gmdate('yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss \G\M\T', time());
```

You should use it like

```
gmdate('Y-m-d h:m:s \G\M\T', time());
```

Answer (score 0):

`gmdate()` is doing exactly what you asked for.

Look at formats here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php