# Convert into format YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: java, datetime

I want this `gmt` time into `YYYY-MM-DD` format but i went through the procedure it give parse exception error.

I want to convert this String type of `Fri Apr 08 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)` into date format so that i can insert into my mqysql data base.

Comment: check this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20159655/how-to-get-gmt-date-in-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-in-php

Comment: Where did that string come from in the first place? If you can possibly avoid getting it as a string (e.g. using a `Date` as your input instead) that would be useful...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get "YYYY-MM-DD" formate of mysql date format this code could help.

```
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd");
        DateTimeFormatter formatter=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss zZ (z)");
        TemporalAccessor parse = formatter.parse("Fri Apr 08 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)");
        LocalDate localDate=LocalDate.from(parse);
        String formated= dateTimeFormatter.format(localDate);

        System.out.println("formated:"+formated);
```