# PHP get current local time based on GMT offset

Tags: php

There is a function `date_default_timezone_set()` in php which accepts timezone string like "UK/London". But unfortunately I have the GMT offset of the user only.

Let's say I am on GMT +5 and I want to get current time based on GMT +5. I did a lot of search on google but did not help.

Since, I do not have the time zone string I am looking for something like

```
$current_date = date("Y M D H:S, "GMT +5");
```

Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get Greenwich Mean Time in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851574/how-do-i-get-greenwich-mean-time-in-php)

Comment: @NorthBridge, the offset is strange there, I don't want offset like $offset=4*60*60;

Comment: @Sarah Why not? It is fairly easy to convert your GMT +5 to 5*60*60 isn't it?

Comment: Since the timezones are not likely to change, you can maybe hardcode an array with the GMT offset as a key and the timezone string (UK/London) as a value and call date_default_timezone_set() ?

Comment: @AlexandreN. That will probably not work, since if the offset is key, it will have to be a multidimensional array (there are many timezone strings for each offset), and things will get nasty.

Comment: @Alexandre No, you cannot. GMT offsets change all the time! (Unintentionally punny?)

Comment: I don't care if GMT offset gets changes all the time. I just need a solution, @deceze

Comment: Still waiting for a nice answer... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only exclusively use GMT offsets for *right now*, i.e. it's completely useless if the user told you his GMT offset half a year ago and you want to know now what time it is at his location. It could basically be anything within a range of a few hours. Even if you got the offset *a few seconds ago*, it may already be different by the time you do the calculations if you happen to hit a DST change exactly.

Having said that, you'll want to add/subtract the offset hours from the formatted time, which is really the only thing you can do.

```
$offset = 5;
$hours  = (gmdate('H') + $offset) % 24;

echo $hours . gmdate(':i:s Y m d');
```

That's just an example, you'll need to handle minute offsets as well.

Comment: You just posted a too complex answer

Comment: Meaning what? You want a simpler function? You don't understand what I wrote?

Comment: @decceze, see the next answer. :D

Answer (score 2):

```
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
$curTime = strtotime("+5 hours");
$current_date = date("Y M D H:S, $curTime);
```

1. set GMT timezone first or get GMT offset。
2. get timestamp
3. timestamp  to date