# php datetime couldn't match to my saved database data

Tags: php, sql, database, datetime, strtotime

Here I select a date: 21 Feb, 2019

```
$ri_arrival_date = $_POST["ri_arrival_date"];
$arvl_date = strtotime($ri_arrival_date);
$arvl_date = date('d M,Y',$arvl_date);
$check_in_date = $ri_arrival_date;
$datetime = new DateTime($arvl_date);
$datetime->setTime(0, 0, 0);
$arvl_date = $datetime->getTimestamp();
echo $arvl_date;
```

`echo` result is `1550703600` (`February 21, 2019 5:00:00 AM`) But in my database it saved by `1550685600` (`February 21, 2019 12:00:00 AM`) Two value is different.

I want to get `1550685600` the database DateTime value. But it couldn't match.

Comment: maybe its related to GMT+5

Comment: So how to fix it.

Comment: explore this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851574/how-do-i-get-greenwich-mean-time-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just use `$datetime->setTime(-5, 0, 0);` to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the server timezone and the mysql timezone if is on a different server.

In all my php I set my timezone based on my location defined instead of the one of the server. This will eliminate the confusion If host my server on another timezone. And also can be expanded/upgrade to accept the user timezone if needed.

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

?>
```