# PHP timezone Asia/Yangon show the wrong timezone

Tags: php, timezone

I found that `Asia/Yangon` is running the wrong timezone. You can see below this picture.

[image: TZE]

But when I use `Asia/Rangoon`, it run the correct timezone that I want. Refer to this [LINK](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php), there is no `Asia/Rangoon`, only have `Asia/Yangon`. So what's the problem why I can't use `Asia/Yangon`, the website is write there...

***If you wonder why I will use `Asia/Rangoon`, I found it at here. Beside Yangon there is Rangoon.**

[image: time]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name `Asia/Yangon` was introduced in September 2016 with [TZDB 2016g](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2016-September/000041.html), where it became the canonical zone name for the time in Myanmar.  At the same time, `Asia/Rangoon` was created as a link entry, making it an alias to preserve backwards compatibility. In other words, `Asia/Rangoon` is an alias for `Asia/Yangon`.  They both refer to the time in Myanmar.

[You can see this change in the tzdb sources here](https://github.com/eggert/tz/commit/4368251ebf11310a4aadccd1910daeac9080c501).

If your PHP installation does not recognize `Asia/Yangon`, then it has a TZDB release earlier to 2016g.  PHP gets its TZDB information via the [timezonedb PECL package](https://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb).  TZDB 2016g corresponds to timezonedb 2016.7, released on 2016-09-28.

PHP itself gets the latest version of timezonedb every time it puts out a release.  Thus, your PHP installation is likely very old and simply needs to be updated.

Comment: I have multiple servers running the same PHP version where some do and some don't support this timezone. So it seems it is not (only) depending on PHP version.

Comment: @Lode - I recommend you check the timezonedb version via [`timezone_version_get()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-version-get.php) on your different servers.

Comment: Sadly that gives `0.system` in both cases. Outside of PHP I did find that the installed `tzdata` package has version differences: `2016d-1.el7` vs `2019b-1.el7`. Will try to update that. But good to know that PHP didn't define this.

Comment: Interesting.  My understanding is that `0.system` is supposed to mean that it uses the version of timezonedb that PHP shipped with.  Perhaps I am mistaken and it is actually using the tzdata of the system directly.  I will check.  Thanks!  - And yes, update your system tzdata. ;)

Comment: @Lode - Are you using PHP's time zone APIs like `DateTimeZone`, or are you using PHP's ICU Intl APIs like `IntlTimeZone`?  The former uses timezonedb, while the latter uses the ICU time zone data.

Comment: Using `DateTimeZone`. Btw, I updated `tzdata` with success.

Answer (score 0):

Its worth saying that as of 2024 and PHP `8.2.16` I am no longer seeing `Asia/Rangoon` as an available option.

```
<?php
echo phpversion();

$tzlist = \DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(\DateTimeZone::ALL);

print'<pre>';print_r($tzlist);print'</pre>';
?>
```

This was a legacy DB entry so I need to update it but the list does show `Asia/Yangon` as per Matts answer.

Answer (score -1):

> Time zone in Yangon, Myanmar (Burma) (GMT+6:30)

```php
  $diffWithGMT=6*60*60+30*60; //converting time difference to seconds.
  $dateFormat="d-m-Y H:i:s";
  $timeAndDate=gmdate($dateFormat, time()+$diffWithGMT);//time() function returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch. 
  echo $timeAndDate; //time in Yangon
```

#### custom timezone can help.

read this [time()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-time-function/) and [change time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851574/how-do-i-get-greenwich-mean-time-in-php)